# setAlarmClock not work when set from reciever

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

In my code I have a broadcast reciever

```
     <receiver
        android:name=".alarm.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.BalDroid.YekNegah.alarm.dailyAction" 
        />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I schedule alarm in this receiver  in onReceive method

```
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmRow.getId(mycursor), i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

                    AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(
                            mycal.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
                   mgr.setAlarmClock(alarmInfo,pi);

                    // Create a Pending intent to show Alarm Details
                }
```

although receiver run but alarm not trigger with `mgr.setAlarmClock`. But  when I use 
 `mgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` alarm trigger

(because of `setAlarmClock` accuracy I have to use `setAlarmClock` in my code)

And when I schedule  `mgr.setAlarmClock` from MainActivity (when start application manually) it works.
I cant find the solution!!.
(I don't know why is not work from receiver).

Comment: Which Android version are you running it in ?

Comment: I run it in android api 26

Answer (score 1):

My app also called `setAlarmClock` on `AlarmManager`, however the event didn't trigger. The reason for me was the default restriction of background processes by the manufacturer(my phone is Xiaomi).

Go to Settings -> Your application and find background restriction options. Turn the restrictions off and `setAlarmClock` must work.

As a conclusion, the result depends on manufacturer's default settings.